# How to fetch url or param in NextJs 13 app directory

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to port my getserversideprops() to next13 and need to use url. How do i fetch params(from the directory structure) or url. My path for the page is `/posts/{postId}`. This is the code I am trying to work with

```js
'use client'

async function fetchOnePost() {
  // need to access URL path or param `{postId}` here
}

export default async function Page() {
    const postData = await fetchOnePost();

return(<>....</>);
}
```

This is my directory structure leading to the file

```
app/
 - posts/
     - [postId]/
         - page.js
```

Basically I want the equivalent app directory code for this below code that is used in pages directory(/pages/post/[postId].js):

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { postId } = context.query;

  const something = somthingDoneWithPostId(postId)

  return { props: { something } };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page) you should be able to do so like this:

```
export default function Page({ params, searchParams }) {
  return <h1>My Page</h1>
}
```

And the same thing using Typescript:

```
export default function Page({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: { slug: string }
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}) {
  return <h1>My Page</h1>
}
```

---

In your specific case, your code would look like this (use a server component):

```
export default async function Page({ params }) {
  const postId = params.postId;

  const something = somethingDoneWithPostId(postId)

  return(<MyComponent something={something} >....<MyComponent/>);
}
```

Comment: I get the aspect of fetching param to use in react components but I want to get the params before that for data fetching. I have updated the question to include an example of what exactly I am trying to do. Hope it helps!

Comment: Wait... I think I get your point. I can directly pass on params.postId to a data fetching function. Got it. Thanks!!

Comment: Exactly! The [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#step-6-migrating-data-fetching-methods) page has some other helpful info about migrating data fetching methods from `pages` to `app` directory